# Excel: Data subtotal copying problem

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, copy-paste

I have a huge data set consisting of 900,000 rows and 11 columns in Excel 2007 format. When I use the `Data > Subtotals` feature I get what I want: 162 rows grouped as I need. The problem is, when I select and copy those 162 rows and paste in a new sheet, Excel pastes all 900,000 rows. I only want to paste 162 rows in a separate sheet. I tried "Paste special" but to no avail. Any clues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at this [link](http://thenewpaperclip.com/2009/02/11/copy-and-paste-sub-totals-in-excel-2007/).

> The problem is that when you select
>   rows using the sub-total outline view,
>   it is selecting every row, not just
>   those sub-totals.  The way to solve
>   this is to only select the visible
>   cells – which means we have to use a
>   feature of Excel called “Go To
>   Special”.  Here is how to do it:
>
> 1) Select all your sub-totals that you
>   want to copy
>
> 2) On the “Home” tab of the Ribbon,
>   look for the “Editing” group – usually
>   it is the last one, all the way over
>   at the right hand side of the Ribbon.
>
> 3) Click on “Find & Select”
>
> 4) On the little menu that appears,
>   click “Go To Special”
>
> 5) In the box that appears, make sure
>   you select “Visible Cells Only” in the
>   right hand column
>
> 6) Click OK
>
> 7) Copy using the menu (or ctrl+c) and
>   then paste your sub-totals in your new
>   spreadsheet

Comment: Does not work...

Comment: The new link provides an answer which works...

Comment: +1 That is good to know. I've always used Word (or a new email) as an intermediary clipboard for that.

Comment: Edit made; link rot prevented.